# How can I dynamically set memcached servers in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, memcached

To give some context. We have a list of memcached servers which changes quite often depending on the status of the server. When a server is being updated or maintained in any way and has to be shut down, we update a database table and then, the server isn't part of the list we use any more (until it's up again).

In Laravel, we tried to set the memcached servers in the config file `config/cache.php` "dynamically" in a ServiceProvider like so :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Config::set(
            'cache.stores.memcached.servers',
            [
                [
                    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                    'port' => 11211,
                    'weight' => 100,
                ],
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

But when we use this, the `Cache` facade returns null on any get we do. If the server is hardcoded in the config file, it returns the right value. Dumping the config variable shows the same thing using both solutions (so the config is set right).

It seems the `Cache` layer boots up using the config, and then it cannot be changed. How can I avoid this behaviour and change the servers dynamically ?

Comment: Try making a new provider and putting it before other providers in the providers section in your `config/app.php`

Comment: @apokryfos It worked, thanks a lot !